# Disabling multiple input fields and checkbox

Tags: javascript

I want the nearest input field to be disabled when I click on a checkbox. Because I dont want repetitive code for each `id` like:

```
document.getElementById('checkBox').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('textBox').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

I decided to use class and a function.
But right now nothing is happening and there are also no errors.

This is my code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player1" value="check" checked> <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player1Name" value="Player1"><br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player2" value="check" checked> <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player2Name" value="Player2"><br><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player3" value="check"> <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player3Name" value="Player3" disabled><br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player4" value="check"> <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player4name" value="Player4" disabled><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Play game!">
  </form>

<script>
    function getClosest(el, tag) {
      // this is necessary since nodeName is always in upper case
      tag = tag.toUpperCase();
      do {
        if (el.nodeName === tag) {
          // tag name is found! let's return it. :)
          return el;
        }
      } while (el = el.parentNode);

      // not found :(
      return null;
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('checkBox').onchange = function() {
        var closestInput = getClosest(this, input);

        closestInput.disabled = !this.checked;
    };
</script>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8an1h0ys/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch all the `checkbox` elements, bind `change` event listener to each of them, and if a specific checkbox is checked, disable corresponding text (with the same `index`) element.

```js
var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBox');
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('textBox');
Array.from(checks).forEach((v,i) => v.addEventListener('change', function(){
  texts[i].disabled = this.checked;
}));
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player1" value="check" > <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player1Name" value="Player1"><br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player2" value="check" > <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player2Name" value="Player2"><br><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player3" value="check"> <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player3Name" value="Player3" ><br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="player4" value="check"> <input type="text" class="textBox" name="player4name" value="Player4" ><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Play game!">
  </form>
```

Comment: Wrong way round :) also could remove the `if` and just do `texts[i].disabled = !this.checked`

Comment: @George This is a great idea, but without the `!` (:

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer after the lock. I used the !this.checked one otherwise the inputfield will be locked when the box is checked.